# NgIf binding img depending from positive negative or equal value Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ng-if

So let me explain it to you, I've got an Observable mapping a Json to my view, I parse it with a ngFor and it's working very well, then I want to display an img(an arrow) depending from that value: if the value is 0 then I show the stable arrow, if the value is negative I show the down arrow, and if it's positive I show the up arrow...if anyone got an idea I'll appreciate :)...please see what I tried bellow:

The question is how could I display the img depending on positive, negative or equal value?

```
  <p class="numbersred" *ngFor="let user of userService.users | async"> {{user.data.apps.availability.trend}}%</p>
             <span *ngIf="user?.data.apps.availability.trend===0">
                <img src="./app/img/icones_sized/stable_arrow_small.png"/>
             </span>                  
             <span *ngIf="user?.data.apps.availability.trend >= 0">
               <img src="./app/img/icones_sized/up_arrow_small.png"/>                                                                   
            </span>
            <span *ngIf="user?.data.apps.availability.trend <= 0">
              <img src="./app/img/icones_sized/down_arrow_small.png"/>
            </span></p>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You're including zero in all the cases

Comment: The question is how could I display the img depending on positive, negative or equal value...I update my post

Comment: @elvin My backend server is returning me theses value depending from other parameters and I have any controls on them

Comment: See Pengyy's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should separate the conditions to `>0`, `=0`, and `<0`.

```
<span *ngIf="user?.data.apps.availability.trend===0">
  <img src="./app/img/icones_sized/stable_arrow_small.png"/>
</span>                  
<span *ngIf="user?.data.apps.availability.trend > 0">
  <img src="./app/img/icones_sized/up_arrow_small.png"/>                                                                   
</span>
<span *ngIf="user?.data.apps.availability.trend < 0">
  <img src="./app/img/icones_sized/down_arrow_small.png"/>
</span>
```

Comment: many thanks looks like your code is correct because I've got any error in the console but I see nothing in the view.. I'll search why ;)

Comment: it works !!! I ve just to play a little bit with css because my arrow is mooving out of my div but it works thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try re-factoring like so.

```
<p class="numbersred" *ngFor="let user of userService.users | async"> {{user.data.apps.availability.trend}}%</p>
             <span *ngIf="user?.data.apps.availability.trend">
                <img src="getImage(user.data.apps.availability.trend)"/>
  </span>  </p>
```

And your component.

```
getImage(trend){

  if (trend === 0)
    return './app/img/icones_sized/stable_arrow_small.png';
  else if (trend > 0)
    return './app/img/icones_sized/up_arrow_small.png';

  return './app/img/icones_sized/down_arrow_small.png';
}
```